# API Explorer 4 under Joomla and Windows/IIS gives fields like {{ ts('CiviCRM API v4') }}

Tags: api, developer, windows

I am running a development system under Joomla and IIS with CiviCRM 5.19.1 (5.19.0 had the same issue).  When using API Explorer 4 I get windows like this.
[image]

Under LAMP, the window makes sense.
[image]
 Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like something is wrong with angular in your browser or civicrm installation.

Comment: Thanks @JaapJansma-CiviCooP.  Where does angular live?  …/administrator/components/com_civicrm/cvicrm/ang?

Comment: Multiple sources and combined and stored in a cache. I am not a joomla expert. But in drupal it helps to clear the cache, and empty sites/default/files/js folder. How that works in Joomla I dont know.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by IIS Request Filtering Hidden Segments.  By default IIS has a hidden segment called bin.  API Explorer 4 attempts to get JavaScript from

.../administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/google-code-prettify/bin/

Notice the bin folder name.  Removing the bin Hidden Segment cured the problem.  Security isn't an issue - the web site is only accessible in the local environment.